# What is the probability of having a common element in two subsets?

Tags: probability

Let $A$ be a set of elements $|A| = n$

$B$ and $C$ are two subsets of $A$ with $|B| = p$ and $|C| = q$

What is the probability of having an element in common between this two subsets ? And how do we evaluate it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to find out the probability that the two sets $B$ and $C$ are disjoint instead; which is easy to evaluate to be
$$\frac{\binom{n}{p} \binom{n - p}{q}}{2^n \times 2^n}$$
so the probability that $B$ and $C$ having common element is
$$1 - \frac{\binom{n}{p} \binom{n - p}{q}}{2^n \times 2^n}$$
(I am assuming $B$ and $C$ are random subsets not necessarily with $p$, $q$ elements.)

**EDIT**: Due to the comment, I just realize that the OP asks for exactly one common element, not at least one. In which case, the answer should be
$$\frac{\binom{n}{p} p \binom{n - p}{q - 1}}{\binom{n}{p} \binom{n}{q}}$$
where the numerator counts the number of possible pairs of $p$-element and $q$-element set with exactly one common element; the denominator is the total number of possible pairs of $p$-element and $q$-element set.

Comment: Using the complement method gives the probability for at least one common element instead of just one common element though.

Comment: That is, **if** $B$ and $C$ are "uniformly distributed" (i.e. $P(\{B=B_1\}) = P(\{B=B_2\}$) - which is likely the case, but it should be stated clearly.